# ToOptimizedResultUsingCache and Redis

Tags: servicestack

I have configured the Redis client as below:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>( new PooledRedisClientManager("url"));
container.Register(c =>c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
```

In this scenario, if during the execution of the ToOptimizedResultUsingCache method, an exception is generated, is it possible to have it not stored as a key in Redis?

```
public object Get( MyRequest request)
{
    return RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache<RedisTestResponse>(base.Cache,
    UrnId.Create<MyRequest >("all"), () =>{
      //throw
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So the exception is thrown and the exception gets stored in redis ?